# Headset Logitech H340: not working properly, sound comes with noises

Tags: sound, usb, pulseaudio, logitech, headset

Logitech H340 usb headset not working properly, sound comes with noises.

I tried to fix it by changing settings inside /etc/pulse/daemon.conf and /etc/pulse/default.pa, also I tried with pipewire audio driver, but the issue remains.

Any idea how to fix this or is it incompatible with Ubuntu 22.04?

```
    Name: alsa_output.usb-Logitech_Inc._Logi_USB_Headset_H340-00.analog-stereo
    Description: Headset H340 Analog Stereo
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 7
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 20190 /  31% / -30.68 dB,   front-right: 20190 /  31% / -30.68 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 58409 /  89% / -3.00 dB
    Monitor Source: alsa_output.usb-Logitech_Inc._Logi_USB_Headset_H340-00.analog-stereo.monitor
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "USB Audio"
        alsa.id = "USB Audio"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "Logi USB Headset H340"
        alsa.long_card_name = "Logitech Inc. Logi USB Headset H340 at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, full speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/sound/card1"
        udev.id = "usb-Logitech_Inc._Logi_USB_Headset_H340-00"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "046d"
        device.vendor.name = "Logitech, Inc."
        device.product.id = "0a38"
        device.product.name = "Headset H340"
        device.serial = "Logitech_Inc._Logi_USB_Headset_H340"
        device.form_factor = "headset"
        device.string = "front:1"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "352800"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "176400"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Headset H340 Analog Stereo"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-headset-usb"
        device.intended_roles = "phone"
    Ports:
        analog-output: Analog Output (type: Analog, priority: 9900, availability unknown)
    Active Port: analog-output
    Formats:
        pcm
```

Comment: title is off topic: we do not support kind of q ;-)  made a more on topic if you don't mind.

Comment: The fact that it connects and there is sound proofs it is compatible. Those extra noices.... I have one thing it might be: the mic might be active so see if you can turn it off  and see if that is it. It might be in "phone mode" and not "audio mode".

Comment: Hi @Rinzwind, my microphone is disabled, it happens when I watch or listen to something, the noise is especially annoying at low volume levels and sounds like an old radio.